# Handle web tables with Shadow DOM in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am struggling to make Cypress see my web table that is in a Shadow DOM. My test Scenario is: After I type invalid data on the search bar, e.g 'oo', Cypress ensures that the table is empty, this means that only the headers: *Name* and *Billing Contact Name* are displayed.

What I did:

1. Installed getTable command: `npm install --save cypress-get-table`
2. Included in the project’s cypress/support/index.js file: `require('cypress-get-table')`

This is the HTML code

[image: HTML code]

And this is my cypress code

```
 it('should type an invalid search', function () {
        cy.get('div.input-container').type('oo{enter}') //type oo in the search bar
//After type oo the table should be cleared

        cy.get('im-data-table.hydrated').shadow().find('div#dataTable').getTable().should(tableData(){
expect(tableData).to.be.empty
    })
})
Problem is: Cypress can not find the table.
Any help is realy appreciated.
```

**Update:**
I put a new picture to have the HTML code more complete. On this new one, we can see the content of the table and the im-root

[image]
and this is the code with multiple .shadow() calls

```
cy.get('im-page.hydrated').shadow()
.find('im-section:nth-of-type(2)') //second im-section
.shadow()
.find('im-data-table.hydrated')
.shadow()
.find('div#dataTable')
.getTable()
.should(function (tableData) {
 expect(tableData).to.be.empty
})
```

With this chained .shadow() calls Cypress does not find the im-section

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in order to ensure the problem does not come from the cypress-get-table plugin, you could assert with "normal Cypress" that the table exists:

```
cy.get('im-data-table.hydrated')
    .shadow()
    .find('div#dataTable')
    .should('exist')
```

Secondly, I think the assertion you are using is incorrect - the `tableData` should be the variable in the assertion function, not the function itself:

```
cy.get('im-data-table.hydrated')
    .shadow()
    .find('div#dataTable')
    .getTable()
    .should(function(tableData){
        expect(tableData).to.be.empty
    })
```

Finally, your `im-data-table.hydrated` is itself in a shadow DOM, which you have to enter - so you have to chain multiple `.shadow()` calls:

```
cy.get('im-page.hydrated')
    .shadow()

    .find('...') // the im-section you're interested in
    .shadow()

    .find('im-data-table.hydrated')
    .shadow()

    .find('div#dataTable')
    .getTable()
    .should(function(tableData){
        expect(tableData).to.be.empty
    })
```

Of course, you can wrap all that code in a function.

Comment: tks @Cycy I got the idea. But I Cypress is still not finding ```im-data-table.hydrated```, so I tried  ```cy.get('im-data-table.hydrated').should('exist')```, but still it is not found. Any thought?

Comment: Beware: your `im-data-table.hydrated` is also in a shadow DOM. I think you have to enter every one of the shadow DOMs with the .shadow() command. I'll update the answer too.

Comment: tks a lot for your help. I updated my question with a picture of the table when it has data and its HTML code + Cypress code with chained Shadow calls. Cypress can not find the ```im-section```

Comment: @IngriddBrito, the `im-section` is directly in the `im-page` div, not in its shadow DOM - maybe you just have one too much `.shadow()` ?